# GraphQL support for ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, graphql-dotnet

Is there support for GraphQL and classic dotnet i.e ASP.NET WebAPI and not dot net core.I searched that on internet but did not find any useful resource.

We have exsisting ASP.NET WebAPI where we need to select and update few columns based on request received to API.so in that case we can use GraphQL. But I did not find any resources related to it.Everywhere is dotnet core apps.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correct, one of most popular lib GraphQL.Net under .Net stack, supports .Net standart 2.0 which means you can build and use it not only under .Net core (target framework should be at least from v4.6.2). At least I did it in one of project (not .net core one) successfully.

Comment: do you have any resources which can guide

Comment: well, only one guide is github - https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet (and ofc, check all tickets - some of known issues there, some are fixed, but only for the v3 which is still in preview release)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Also while searching on Google I find one more lib https://hotchocolate.io/